# Get value of selected item in binded listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, observablecollection

I want to get a `string` value on `doubleclick` event of a selected item that's displayed in a `listbox`. I'm using mvvm architecture.
Below is the code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RecentProjects}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>
                         <Run Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
                         <Run Text="{Binding CreationTime}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListBox>
```

Code in my ViewModel is like below:

```
private ObservableCollection<FileItem> _recentProjects = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();
public ObservableCollection<FileItem> RecentProjects
    {
        get { return _recentProjects; }
        set { _recentProjects = value; }
    }

public RelayCommand SelectedCommand { get; private set; }
private void Selected()
    {
        //string fileName = RecentProjects.SelectedItem ===> Need stringvalue of filename
    }
```

And, in the FileItem model I have a FileName and a  `CreationTime` Property.
I want to get the string value of of FileName of the selecteditem in the RecentProjects Observablecollection. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a Property as your `ListBox.SelectedItem`:

Your view-model:

```
    FileItem _myItem;
    public FileItem MyItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _myItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _myItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyItem");
        }
    }

    private void Selected()
    {
        string fileName = MyItem.FileName;
    }
```

your Xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RecentProjects}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyItem}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate> ...
```